# How do I see the permissions granted on a service account from the command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've found commands line `gcloud auth list` and `gcloud auth activate-service-account` but I don't see a way to list current permissions on a service account. The console only lets me see the old pre-baked permission list.

Answer (score 4):

Within the Cloud Shell, you may run the command below. [This command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy) will list all the service accounts within a project and list all the service accounts' permissions.

`$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-name]`